# Why can't I clone a bitbucket repository with correct credentials?

Tags: git, bitbucket

So I ran this on my server:

ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

And got "You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled."
It also said: "This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:" - listing the repository that I needed to clone.

And I would still get the "Permission denied" error when I tried to git clone the repository it said I have access to.

Comment: Because you are trying to ssh into bitbucket.org and not a repository on bitbucket

Comment: @Popeye I think you misread the question. I was actually using a 'git clone' command and was getting permission denied for a repository for which the output of "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org" said I have access to

Comment: Just to cover all the bases: when you run `git clone`, you're using the SSH URL, right?

Comment: @JimRedmond I was using the url that I copied from bitbucket i.e. 

git clone git@bitbucket.org:project/repository.git